# How to get Location with Wifi in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-location, location-provider

I Want get location with Wifi and work in Google map, and it's not work for me but Gps is okay and not problem.

my code:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

if (locationManager != null) {
    boolean gpsIsEnabled = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean networkIsEnabled = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (gpsIsEnabled) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000L, 10F,
                (android.location.LocationListener) this);
    } else if (networkIsEnabled) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000L, 10F,
                (android.location.LocationListener) this);
    } else {
        // Show an error dialog that GPS is disabled...
    }
} else {
    // Show some generic error dialog because something must have gone
    // wrong with location manager.
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyB4C_zHeHYMTWqW4_Wpin-5jLF9S54KDSQ" />
</application>

<permission
android:name="com.karyan.karyanmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.karyan.karyanmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"  />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.camera"
android:required="false" >
</uses-feature>
<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true" />
```

Newtork_Provider is null when wifi in connected to Intenet.. How to Resolve Problem

thanks..

Comment: Well, per your code, GPS has precedence when looking into providers.

Comment: why wifi is not work and always null?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668917/how-to-get-the-coarse-location-using-wifi-or-gsm-or-gps-whichever-is-available

Comment: i use above link GpsTracker but Nework_Provider is Null... Intenet in Perfect and any Problem :(

Comment: refer this one maybe helpful....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419695/android-google-maps-xml-layout-errors/18419989#18419989

Comment: its not work beacuase wifi there arent from link

Comment: @sr.farzad hey can you tell how you solved your problems

Answer (score 5):

Say, can I setup "request Location Update" for GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER (or PASSIVE_PROVIDER) to same function call like this:

```
// SETUP Location Manager
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

In this case, I get only GPS data.