# Latitude Longitude Through Internet

Tags: android

I built the Application Which take lat lng from gps but most of time it does not work is there Any way to get lat lng from internet..

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, locationListenerGps);
```

Comment: What do you mean by **most of time**? Have you set permissions? Have you enabled GPS? Have you set the type of accuracy?

Comment: Yes i Set when i am in room app can't work

Comment: It takes time to load GPS data indoors. That's why most of the times it does not seem to work.

Comment: Can we take lat,lng from internet..

Comment: @HUSNAINSARWAR check this. link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826718/how-to-get-location-with-wifi-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826718/how-to-get-location-with-wifi-in-android)

Comment: you can never get the LatLong from internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is  Mainly two ways to get current location.

**1> Using GPS**
[see this link for get location using GPS](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/)

In GPS it Sometime not give exactlocation so if your network enable then it try to get location from network provider. for eg. when you are in basement that time GPS sometime not give exact location.

**2>Using Fused Location**
[see this link for get Location using Fused location](http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/10/fused-location-provider-in-android.html)

Fused Location is mostly use when you want to continue get location in some time interval.